# Android Studio Gradle Library setup

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I've been struggling with getting external libraries to work properly. When you import a library, it gets copied into the project's directory structure. I'd like to avoid this as I have libraries I use in many projects, and these libraries get updated on a fairly frequent basis.

So these are the libraries I'm trying to get setup right now:

aal - This is a general use library that I use across several applications. This android library has no external dependencies.

aal_amazon - This is a library for accessing Amazon specific APIs. This library depends on aal, and has the Amazon game circle SDK in it.

aal_google - This library is for google APIs. This library depends on google play services, and also aal.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to set a project's dependency to either aal_amazon, or aal_google, and by extension, the project should have access to aal.

I know you can use project(':aal').projectDir = new File('path/to/file') to set the library's folder location, however I seem to be having the issue because the amazon, and google libs have their own dependencies.

Is there a way to set things up so in a project, I just put this in the settings.gradle:

```
include ':app'
include ':aal_amazon'
project(':aal_amazon').projectDir= new File('/path/to/aal_amazon')
```

Where the above would give the project access to aal_amazon, AND aal?

Comment: It's not designed to do what you want; in general all knowledge about what modules a project includes has to live in your project's settings.gradle file. What you're effectively asking is for aal_amazon and aal_google to have their own settings.gradle file to pull in aal, but multiple settings.gradle files aren't supported. I'm not posting this as an answer because I'm not saying it's impossible to hack this; Gradle files are after all complete programs and it's likely possible.

Comment: I had a feeling this would be the answer. In some ways, AS/Gradle is better than Eclipse/Ant, but I'm finding there are still things that are better/easier in Eclipse/Ant, and this is a big one. Thanks for the reply.